Power Automate Cloud Flow 403 calling Databricks REST API
I am trying to call Databricks REST API from Power Automate flow and getting 403 "Unauthorized access to workspace". The first steps of the flow is to get a Bearer Token and the second one is calling a procedure. The scope is correctly set for all the apis. The first request goes through fine and I am able to get a token. But the second one is failing with 403. The same flow works fine in Postman and all the permission for the Service principal on the Databricks side are validated. As an additional validation, I tried to use the Bearer Token from the Power Apps in the Postman to query and it goes fine which leaves me wondering what's missing in my Power Apps flow. I would appreciate any inputs to fix the issue.
Request:
    {
    "uri": "https://adb-xxxxxxxx.12.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/sql/statements",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer Token",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "statement": "A select query \n",
        "warehouse_id": "warehouseid"
    }
}
Response: {
"statusCode": 403,
"headers": {
    "X-Request-ID": "f7b4f4c6",
    "x-databricks-reason-phrase": "Unauthorized access to workspace: ",
    "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "Date": "Wed, 18 Dec 2024 23:34:04 GMT",
    "Server": "databricks",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-Length": "81"
},
"body": {
    "error_code": 403,
    "message": "Unauthorized access to workspace: "
}

}

have you tried with giving token from generated from databricks? is it working?

Follow below steps to get access token and make sql statements request.

Create web service to get access token with below details.

URL : https://<host_name>.azuredatabricks.net/oidc/v1/token
Method: POST
Content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Request body
grant_type=client_credentials&scope=all-apis&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<Your_seceret>



You will get response as text convert it to object using
Convert JSON to custom object component.


Here add the response of your web service from previous step.

Next again create web service with below details.

URL : https://<host_name>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/sql/statements
Method: POST
Content type: application/json
Custom headers: Authorization: Bearer %JsonAsCustomObject['access_token']%
Request body
{
    "statement": "select 1 as one",
    "warehouse_id": "cc51079db3510efa"
}


You give the custom json object variable in authorization header like
Bearer %JsonAsCustomObject['access_token']%
you will the results in response.
Flow:

Output:

